# >.. as postfix in Swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement, range

I'm trying to create different cases matching ranges in a switch statement to check user's age:

```
let minimumAge: Int
let maximumAge: Int

if let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date, to: Date()).year {
    switch age {
    case ..<minimumAge:
        return .young
    case (maximumAge+1)... :
        return .old
    default:
        return .valid
    }
}
```

I would like to use something like `>..` to exclude `maximumAge` from executing the case `.old`. Is that possible?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  How about switching your last two cases: `case minimumAge...maximumAge: return .valid default: return .old`.

Comment: Yeah, I like that better than adding 1 to maximumAge

Comment: A plain old if-elseif-else would to the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `...` (maximumAge, which is you have done) or use `minimumAge...maximumAge` as suggest by @vacawama in the above comment, there's nothing like `>..`

```
switch age {
    case ..<minimumAge:
        return .young
    case minimumAge...maximumAge :
        return .valid
    default:
        return .old
    }
```